# CakePHP connect to remote database

Tags: mysql, cakephp, remote-access

i am trying to connect to a remote database using the following code:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '***.unoeuro-****.com',
    'login' => '*********',
    'password' => '**************',
    'database' => '************',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

Now when i try this i get the following error message:

```
    2013-09-13 16:10:55 Error: [MissingConnectionException] Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Mysql',
  'message' => 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host \'****.unoeuro-server.com\' (2)',
  'enabled' => true,
)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote server from localhost?

Comment: It seems like the remote URl is wrong or doesn't allow connections. Did you check the remote host?

Comment: You could/should also check the port of the external DB - it could be different. But first check if it really allows connections from the outside ;)

Comment: @baordog yes i am connecting from localhost

Comment: You may not have a choice, but generally doing this sort of thing is much easier with everything on a server. There are plenty of affordable servers for learning. If you check PHP questions on here, there are many, many examples of people having issue with their XAMP, WAMP, and LAMP set ups.

Comment: @baordog we are three developers working on the same thing in our own seperate branch. To make sure that all of us has the same database we wish to use the remote one. this is why it is so important that we can connect to the remote database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your database server is external resource, make sure you do not have firewall blocking the request from your application.

Comment: I do not think there is a firewall blocking my direct request

Answer (score 0):

If You are connecting to a remote Database from local host, you need to enable remote MySQL from the server you are trying to connect to. Its a security feature